# How do we select multiple dropdown HTML for updating data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, pivot-table, html-select, nested-loops

I have a problem updating the Laravel account table with its groups. I want Laravel to select that account's dropdown list ID in the pivot table, but it shows a duplicate dropdown list due to the wrong nested loop. What can I do?

**Account Controller**

```
public function edit(string $id)
{
    $account = Account::find($id);
    $groups = Group::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
    $pages = Page::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

    return view('accounts.edit', compact('account', 'groups', 'pages'));
}
```

**edit.blade.php**

```
@foreach( $groups as $gr_id => $gr_name ) /** Get all data from db to show in html dropdown **/
    @foreach ($account->group as $group_data)  /** get the selected dropdown from pivot table **/ 
        @if ( $gr_id == $group_data->id ) /** compare their id the selected dropdown **/
            <option value="{{ $gr_id }}" selected> {{ $gr_name }}</option>
        @else 
            <option value="{{ $gr_id }}"> {{ $gr_name }}</option>
        @endif  
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

This issue relates to the nested loop for the wrong coding technique. Could you please correct me?

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through all groups once and then check if the current group is in the account's groups. You can achieve this by using the `contains` method provided by Laravel's collections.

```html
@foreach( $groups as $gr_id => $gr_name )
    @if ($account->group->contains('id', $gr_id))
        <option value="{{ $gr_id }}" selected> {{ $gr_name }}</option>
    @else 
        <option value="{{ $gr_id }}"> {{ $gr_name }}</option>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can use a simpler approach to check if the group is selected. Here's an updated code of your 'edit.blade.php' file

```
@foreach($groups as $gr_id => $gr_name)
    <option value="{{ $gr_id }}" {{ $account->group->contains('id', $gr_id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
        {{ $gr_name }}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

- contains('id', $gr_id) checks if the current group ID is present in the collection of selected groups
- If true, it adds the 'selected' attribute to the option, indicating that it should be pre-selected
- This should help you avoid duplicates and simplify your code.